# Chrome refuses to clear cached Java application

Tags: java, google-chrome, caching

I am testing a java applet in the chrome web browser, and it refuses to change from the old .class file to the new .class file.

I have tried using control+f5, I have tried browsing in icognito mode, I deleted the .class file and recompiled, not even clearing the cache in the settings menu will get Chrome to update from the old .class file to the new one.

I have already run the new application successfully in Firefox.

Question: How can I force Chrome to use a new .class?

```
<html>

<head>
<title>Applet</title>
</head>

<body bgcolor="grey">
Program&#62;&#62;&#62;
<br/>
<applet code="HelloWorldApplet.class" width="300" height="300"></applet>
<br/>
&#60;&#60;&#60;Program
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I suppose you could compile it with `ClassName_versionNumber` whenever you want to push new releases, though that would get annoying in a development environment.

Comment: but did you clear cache in the java console, a program that lives separately from your browser? Welcome to java in the browser, it's become a progressively more horrible thing, opens up users to potentially massive security breaches, and works based on settings not contained in the browser. Oh, and at this point can't really do anything that JavaScript can't. So you probably want to step away from it again -at least in the browser- until you *have* to use it =)

Comment: I think you're right. Java is a huge pain in the ass and javascript has grown up a lot over the last few years. I think I'm going to throw everything out and start over in javascript.